# How do I the calculate the sqrt of a natural or rational number in coq?

Tags: coq, square-root, sqrt

I'm learning coq and I'm trying to make my own Point and Line data types.  I'd like to make a function that returns the length of a line, but I can't seem to find the sqrt function that will return a calculation.  I tried used `Coq.Reals.R_sqrt`, but apparently that's only used for abstract math, so it won't run the calculation.

So then I tried importing `Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract.NSqrt` and `Coq.Numbers.NatInt.NZSqrt.` but neither put sqrt function into the environment.

This is what I have so far...

```
Require Import Coq.QArith.QArith_base.
Require Import Coq.Numbers.NatInt.NZSqrt.
Require Import Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract.NSqrt.
Require Import Coq.ZArith.BinInt.

Inductive Point : Type :=
  point : Q -> Q -> Point.

Inductive Line : Type :=
  line : Point -> Point -> Line.

Definition line_fst (l:Line) :=
  match l with
  | line x y => x
  end.

Definition line_snd (l:Line) :=
  match l with
  | line x y => y
  end.

Definition point_fst (p:Point) :=
  match p with
  | point x y => x
  end.

Definition point_snd (p:Point) :=
  match p with
  | point x y => y
  end.

(* The reference sqrt was not found in the current environment. *)
Definition line_length (l:Line) :=
  sqrt(
    (minus (point_snd(line_fst l)) (point_fst(line_fst l)))^2 
    +
    (minus (point_snd(line_snd l)) (point_fst(line_snd l)))^2
  ).

Example line_example : (
  line_length (line (point 0 0) (point 0 2)) = 2
).
```

Comment: You'll need to decide what *type* you want the square root to have, and what you want to happen when the square root doesn't exist.  For example, what value and type do you want `line_length (line (point 0 0) (point 1 1))` to return?

Comment: I would want the type to be a real number, and then restrict the square root to only positive numbers - which should happen if I only take the square root of (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 -y2)^2.  That's guaranteed to always be a positive number.  But then cast the real number to a rational number if possible?  Otherwise, I'm not sure.  Can coq output values exprssed as a square root?  So for example the distance between point(0,0) and point(1,1) would output the sqrt(2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your square root to compute, there are two things you can do.

- Use the [CoRN library](https://github.com/c-corn/corn). Then you will get real number functions that actually compute. However, those real numbers will just be functions that you can ask for approximations to a certain precision, so might not be what you are looking for. Also, I think CoRN is not terribly well maintained nowadays.
- Use the natural number square root from the standard library that you already mentioned, and use that to calculate the square roots that you want to a certain precision yourself. This function you get by importing`BinNat`:

  ```
  Coq < Require Import BinNat.
  [Loading ML file z_syntax_plugin.cmxs ... done]

  Coq < Eval compute in N.sqrt 1000.  
        = 31%N
        : N
  ```